# Access VBA - Product search fails

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to find all the codes in a filed that match at least with a character. So, If I write down 'a' I would like to know all the code names that contain an 'a' inside them. If I write 'anaconda' and this code exists, with at least one register, the function should found it.

```
Private Function VerificaProducto(ByVal Codigo, ByVal Familia, ByVal Proveedor) As String

    Dim Horno As Database
    Dim Panes As Recordset

    Set Horno = CurrentDb

    If Proveedor = "Cuetara" Then
        Set Panes = Horno.OpenRecordset("almacenpanes", dbOpenDynaset)

        If Familia Like "Integral" Then 
            Panes.FindFirst "codigo = ' " & "*" & Codigo & "*" & " ' and activo = true and tipo = 'Hidratos' and familia LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'"
        Else
            Panes.FindFirst "codigo = ' " & "*" & Codigo & "*" & " ' and activo = true and tipo = 'Hidratos' and familia NOT LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'"
        End If
    End If

    If Panes.NoMatch Then
        Me!NombreProducto = "CODIGO NO PRESENTE EN LAS TABLAS"
        VerificaProducto = "producto no encontrado"
    Else
        VerificaProducto = "producto encontrado"
    End If

End Function
```

Any idea of why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

You're including two literal spaces in your search string: here: `' " &` and here `& "*" & " '`

This means you're only matching when codigo starts and ends with a space.

Scrap those spaces:

```
If Familia Like "Integral" Then 
    Panes.FindFirst "codigo = '" & "*" & Codigo & "*" & "' and activo = true and tipo = 'Hidratos' and familia LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'"
Else
    Panes.FindFirst "codigo = '" & "*" & Codigo & "*" & "' and activo = true and tipo = 'Hidratos' and familia NOT LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'"
End If
```

Also, I recommend considering using an escape function to double up single quotes. If condigo contains a single quote, your function will run into a run-time error, and afaik there's no way to fix that using parameters if you're going to use `.FindFirst`

A further note:  `and familia NOT LIKE '*'&'INTEGRAL'&'*'` is confusing to me, it looks like you're trying to concatenate strings from VBA but you aren't. I recommend using `and familia NOT LIKE '*INTEGRAL*'` instead, to be clear you're using a constant and not a variable.

`If Familia Like "Integral" Then` is similarly confusing. If you want to check if `Familia` contains the string `"Integral"`, use `If Familia Like "*Integral*" Then`. If you want to test for an exact match, use `If Familia = "Integral" Then`